# Can't get panels to display in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to design a calculator shell (non-functioning calculator) using Java but for some reason I cannot get the program to display my buttons. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.awt.*;    
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.color.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {

    public Calculator() {
        JPanel P1 = new JPanel();
        P1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        //Panel Buttons
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            P1.add(new JButton("" + i));
        }
        P1.add(new JButton("" + 0));
        P1.add(new JButton("."));
        P1.add(new JButton("*"));
        P1.add(new JButton("/"));
        P1.add(new JButton("+"));
        P1.add(new JButton("-"));
        P1.add(new JButton("="));
        P1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        P1.setForeground(new Color(100, 1, 1));
        //Content panel
        JPanel P2 = new JPanel();
        P2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        P2.add(new JTextField("Hello world"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        P2.add(P1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator frame = new Calculator();
        frame.setTitle("Simple Calculator");
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

OK here is what I have now...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;   

public class Calculator extends JFrame
{
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
Calculator()
{
    super("Wk 3 Calculator"); setBounds(100,100,300,100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container con = this.getContentPane();
    con.add(p1);
    con.add(p2);
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
    //Panel Buttons
for (int i =1; i <=9; i++){
    p1.add(new JButton ("" + i));
}
    p1.add(new JButton (""+0)); 
    p1.add(new JButton ("."));      
    p1.add(new JButton ("*"));
    p1.add(new JButton ("/"));
    p1.add(new JButton ("+"));
    p1.add(new JButton ("-"));
    p1.add(new JButton ("="));
    //Content panel
    p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p2.add (new JTextField("Hello world"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    //Frame specs
    Calculator frame = new Calculator();
    frame.setSize(250,250);
    frame.setTitle("Simple Calculator");
    frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
    public static void main(String[] args){new Calculator();}           
}
```

It is still not working :(

Comment: Try to stick to the Java convention and start variable names with a small letter!

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding anything to the frame...

Try something along the lines of

```
add(P1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(P2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

For starters...

You might like to have a look at

- [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 1):

add your P2 inside `JFrame`

```
this.add(P2);
this.pack();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the panels to the Frame. Put `add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH)` and `add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH)` at the end of your constructor.

```
public Calculator()
{
    //rest of the construtor
    add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

And rename them so they start with a small letter. Capital letters are for class names.

Answer (score 0):

Well:

1). Call Swing-related code on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread), not on the main thread. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more details.

2). You're not adding the `P1` and `P2` panels to the `JFrame`, so when you display the frame, it doesn't contain anything. Try calling `add (P1)` and `add (P2)`.

3). You should call `frame.pack()` before you call `frame.setVisible (true)`.

**EDIT**:

I rewrote your code (you still have a loong way into making a functional application, but it's a start):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;   

public class Calculator
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public Calculator()
    {
        frame = new JFrame ("Simple Calculator");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            panel.add (new JButton ("" + i));
        }

        panel.add(new JButton (""+0)); 
        panel.add(new JButton ("."));      
        panel.add(new JButton ("*"));
        panel.add(new JButton ("/"));
        panel.add(new JButton ("+"));
        panel.add(new JButton ("-"));
        panel.add(new JButton ("="));

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add (new JTextField("Hello world"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                new Calculator();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.add(P2);
this.pack();
this.repain();`